# same element different clientWidth values across different versions of IE

Tags: html

I have the code like below to get 'content' width, but how come it returns with different values for IE 7,8,9? The value is also different for Firefox.

How can I make it returns the consistent value? Is it possible without using JQuery?

```
document.getElementById('content').clientWidth
document.getElementById('leftSide').offsetWidth
document.getElementById('content').clientHeight
```

leftside div is contained inside of content div. The only style they have is

```
background-color:white;
```

I got:

IE7 1604/297/925

IE8 1906/297/925

IE9 1910/297/1609.

FF  1610/297/1910

I tried to switch on the "standards-compliant mode" but still didn't make a difference...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well, what values are you getting and how large is the element really? Does it have a scroll bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference has to do with the browsers box model. Largely depends if you're in quirks mode or not (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug). The most effective way to mitigate these issues is to use JavaScript library that has methods for normalizing the differences between browsers (e.g., jQuery's `.width()` `.height()` ).